# How can I combine several rows into one using SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table punches that looks like this

```
EMP_ID    INpunchDATETIME     OUTpunchDATETIME
-----------------------------------------------
1         2017-11-10 11:59    2017-11-10 13:30
1         2017-11-10 9:00     2017-11-10 10:30
```

I need to create a table @temptable from the previous table that looks like this

```
Emp_ID InPunch1         InPunch2          OUTpunch1         OUTpunch2 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      2017-11-10 9:00  2017-11-10 11:59  2017-11-10 10:30  2017-11-10 13:30
```

I'm trying to use PIVOT but if that's wrong I can change

```
DECLARE @temptable Table (
        EMP_ID int,
        InPunch1 datetime,
        InPunch2 datetime,
        OutPunch1 datetime,
        OutPunch2 datetime);

SELECT
    Emp_ID, InPunch1, InPunch2, Outpunch1, Outpunch2
INTO
    @temptable
FROM 
    (SELECT
         EMP_ID, INPunchDATETIME, OUTpunchDATETIME
     FROM 
         punches) AS p
PIVOT
    (
```

That's as far as I've got.

Comment: I'm assuming the number of punches are infinite?

Comment: I'm not sure PIVOT is what you're looking for: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Something like this might work: Select top 1 p.Emp_ID, p2.InPunch as Inpunch1, p.InPunch as inpunch2, p2.Outpunch as outpunch1, p.Outpunch as outpunch2
FROM testing p INNER JOIN testing p2 ON p.EMP_ID = p2.EMP_ID
AND p.INpunch <> p2.INpunch
AND DAY(p.INpunch ) = DAY(p2.INpunch)

Comment: However, you have syntax errors in the temptable declaration and problem description needs to be fleshed out, e.g. I assume this is trying to track split shifts, however, nothing is mentioned about ensure punch in/out occur in the same day, etc.

Comment: I was trying to make the question more generic so it would be more helpful to others.  Yes, I plan to add some logic to make sure that all the punches occurred on the same day.  Also I've got the data in one database and need to send to another.  The sending database is formatted like my first example and the receiving database is formatted like the 2nd.

Comment: Number of punches are not infinite.  The table in the database I need to write to has 6 ins and 6 outs.  Each record is for one employee on one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample Data Setup**

```
create table dbo.punches
    (
        emp_id int
        , INpunchDATETIME datetime
        , OUTpunchDATETIME datetime
    )

insert into dbo.punches
values (1, '2017-11-10 11:59','2017-11-10 13:30')
    , (1, '2017-11-10 9:00','2017-11-10 10:30')
```

**Answer**

The punches tables has the in/out punches in two separate column, and the inner most query moves both types of punches into one column to allow all of the data to be `pivot`ed at once. The next query puts them in chronological order, and creates values in `punch_ind` that will be the eventual column names. Last step is to `pivot` the data and select the final output.

```
select post.emp_id
, post.InPunch1
, post.InPunch2
, post.OutPunch1
, post.OutPunch2
from (
    --decide which punch is in1/in2/etc.
    select sub.emp_id
    , sub.punch_type + 'Punch' + cast(row_number() over (partition by sub.emp_id, sub.punch_type order by sub.punch_ts) as varchar(10)) as punch_ind --punch indicator
    , sub.punch_ts
    from (
        --get all of the data in one column to enable pivot
        select p.emp_id
        , 'In' as punch_type
        , p.INpunchDATETIME as punch_ts
        from dbo.punches as p
        union all
        select p.emp_id
        , 'Out' as punch_type
        , p.OUTpunchDATETIME as punch_ts
        from dbo.punches as p
        ) as sub
    ) as pre --before the pivot
pivot (max(pre.punch_ts) for pre.punch_ind in ([InPunch1], [InPunch2], [OutPunch1], [OutPunch2])) as post --after the pivot
```

Just take this final output and `insert` the records into the temp table/table variable of your choice.

Comment: YES! That works perfectly.  I only have one problem.  I'm trying to add logic to select only punches from yesterday.  I added

Where InPunchDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -1, convert(date, GETDATE())) and InPunchDateTime < convert(date, GETDATE())

But I can't figure out where to add it.

Comment: You saved my life!

Comment: Glad I could help!